# Can't call getElementsByTagName on a node in Xerces or Neko?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xerces, neko

hi all I'm trying to parse a DOM tree using Neko/Xerces in Java.

```
NodeList divs = this.doc.getElementsByTagName("DIV");
for(int i=0; i < divs.getLength(); i++) {
    NodeList images = divs.item(i).parentNode().getElementsByTagName("IMG");
    // operate on these
}
```

is what I'd ideally like to do. It seems I can only call `getElementsByTagName` on the document itself? Am I doing something wrong? Should I be able to call that on a `Node` element?

I can see from the docs it's not there: http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/apiDocs/org/w3c/dom/Node.html so maybe I need to do it another way?

thanks!

Answer (score 9):

A NodeList only returns Nodes and getElementsByTagName is only available on an [Element node](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html) You therefore need to cast your Node to an element, here's an example below.

```
final NodeList images = ((Element)divs.item(i).getParentNode()).getElementsByTagName("IMG");
```

However be careful with this as it *assumes* that getParentNode() always returns an Element

This would be safer, but a lot more verbose

```
final Node n = divs.item(i).getParentNode();

if(n instanceof Element) {
    final Element e = (Element)n;
    e.getElementsByTagName("IMG");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's weird.  Python's xml.dom.minidom has a Node.getElementsByTagName.  Maybe it's not part of the standard.  Instead, you could iterate an inner loop over `divs.item(i).parentNode().getChildNodes()`.